# Quasar Electron build not working on M1 mac mini with arm64 architecture

Tags: macos, electron, quasar, electron-packager, apple-m1

I have a Quasar/Electron project and simply trying to build the app via `yarn build` (which equals to `quasar build -m electron` in **package.json**). Previous to my M1 Mac mini upgrade I used to get the following folder structure:

```
/dist/electron/MyApp-darwin-x86
/dist/electron/UnPackaged
```

Now I'm just getting:

```
/dist/electron/UnPackaged
```

I've tried running it with all sorts of flags/configurations but just can't seem to figure out how to build this on the new Mac. Has anyone else had similar issues?

I have the following dependencies:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK well, I fixed it (sort of).

I basically switched from `electron-packager` to `electron-builder` and had to manually update the `dmg-builder` npm package to: **22.10.3** (latest package on 12/14/20)

[image]

Now after building I get my `/dist/electron/Packaged` folder as expected:

[image]

Comment: Are you on windows or mac? I try the achieve the same as you,  but on a windows platform (trying to get a MAC build on windows)